# Can able to configure the flow in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on, keycloak-services, identity-management

i want to expose /home to public and need kecloak auth for rest all endpoints. How should i configure it?

i have added a new client and set valid redirect as http://localhost:3000/*
and web origins as http://localhost:3000
enabled "direct access grant",enabled "standard flow enabled" and enabled "backchannel logout session required"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.